# Is an 'Or' circuit what I'm looking for?

Tags: 12v, fan

12V DC 10-30 amps, dual input relay. Should this be an 'Or' circuit?

Back Story - classic car, currently completing an EFI conversion, which is more or less separate from my quest, but it initiated this current quest. I'm looking for the correct way to use a relay that would provide power to something if either of 2 inputs were providing voltage. If neither input was providing voltage, then no volate output. If 1 of the inputs is providing input voltage, or both of the inputs are providing input voltage simultaneously, then there is a voltage output, without increasing the intended voltage or amperage of the output lead.

I just recently did a fuel injection conversion on my 66 Mustang, and I purchased this specific 6 relay bank https://www.painlessperformance.com/wc/30108 for the purpose of providing a switched 12v source, present with the key at run and start, to the various components of the EFI system. (3 components of the 5 total in the system need this switched 12v source, in addition to straight battery + & -. I bought the 6 bank relay kit, with the idea of using the 3 I need for the EFI, and the other 3 to run an electric radiator cooling fan and the 2 headlights. This was my first time with relays, so I'm not sure how varied the wiring approaches are, so there is a picture here of the wiring for these specific relays. I have 3 extra at my disposal, which of course I'd like to use to save money but I'll get whatever type of relay I may need to solve this problem.[image]

The new EFI kit comes with a lead controlled by the ECU that provides an activation signal to turn on an electric fan (if present) when the engine temp reaches the set threshold. This lead is not meant to provide the power directly to the fan, but meant to control a relay that would provide power to the fan when this signal was present. In that simple scenario, I'm 100% clear on moving forward, using the relays I have to achieve that outcome, but the extra wrench in the works is the air conditioner. I also need the electric fan to be on, if the AC is running inside the car, to pull air across and cool down the AC condensor, so just the signal from the ECU wouldn't accomplish this. Combining the ECU fan signal and a source signal from the AC to indicate power on doesn't work, because then the ECU signal would also activate the AC circuitry, backwards through that connection.

I need to determine the best way to create a relay circuit that would achieve the following:

- -Power provided to the fan comes from the battery or alternator and the relay is using the input signals to determine when to provide
  that power.
  -Engine temp above 'xxx' degrees (input signal 1, from ECU present), but AC not running = 12v, 20A output power present to fan
  -AC running (input signal 2, from AC present), but engine temp at or below 'xxx' degrees = 12v, 20A output power present to fan
  -Engine temp above 'xxx' degrees (input signal 1 from ECU present), **AND** AC running (input signal 2, from AC present) = 12v 20A output power present to fan
  -Neither input signal back-feeds into the other system

A Diode comes to mind, and if there is a way to wire the relays so that the 12v 20A output signal is constant, and the relay is just controlling whether or not that output power passes through, then would the voltage drop from using a diode be a concern? I'm honestly not sure there.

You tell me... what's my smartest path forward? I have power and ground distribution blocks present in the engine bay and a high output 140A fused alternator installed so there's no shortage of places to easily pick up power and ground sources at ample strength for an ideal solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you have two DC voltage sources that share a common ground (return)

AND IF you do not want one source to back-feed the other if the other is not on

THEN one solution is called a diode-OR.

Two power diodes, both cathodes tied together and tied to the load, one anode to each of the voltage sources.  If both sources are on and their voltages are more than 1 V or so different, the higher one will supply almost all of the current.  As the two sources get closer to equal, the current sharing will move toward 50/50 (a variation of "droop sharing").

You can add a relay to assure that only one source supplies all of the current when both are on.

Comment: Awesome, thanks AnalogKid. Do you know of anyone that sells them as pre-made units, with leads ready to solder in? I don't mind spending the extra money to get the cleanest look possible in the engine bay. My google searches based on your answer seem to just be pulling up standard auto relays. Or is there a label/type/identifier in the description or name of premade relay circuits that would indicate they're a diode OR? Or do I need to just make one?

Comment: I think you misunderstand.  The diode-or thing is not a relay unit, it is two diodes.  Note that at high currents, these usually don't have leads, and might require a heatsink.  There are dual-diode units that connect with screws and ring terminals.

Comment: No, I got ya. I understood, but phrased my follow up incorrectly. Two diodes essentially creating a 'Y' with the cathode ends together, feeding the fan and restricting current from flowing backwards to either source, and from that cathode end I could also put a relay in line before the fan, to instead have that diode OR simply trigger the relay to then provide direct battery power to the fan. I get that, and thanks again!

Comment: I was just wondering if anyone was in the business making set-ups like that as pre-assembled units in tidy little black boxes with rectifiers and heat sinks all inside, to match the look of all the other new electrical nonsense in the engine bay, but I can fabricate one easily enough as well. I need to measure the amps on the two signal inputs tonight, to know what I need for diodes. Assuming correct diodes matched for current, at what point would the current be considered 'high draw' enough, that the heat would be too much for it to exist in  loom, and necessitate the heat sink? Thanks again.